# Finding time complexity of a program

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm solving the following programming question:

```
Given a sorted integer array and a number, find the start and end indexes of the number in the array. 

Ex1: Array = {0,0,2,3,3,3,3,4,7,7,9} and Number = 3 --> Output = {3,6} 
Ex2: Array = {0,0,2,3,3,3,3,4,7,7,9} and Number = 5 --> Output = {-1,-1} 

Complexity should be less than O(n)
```

My Solution is as follows:

```
public static void  findStartEndIndex(int[] arr, int elem) {

      int elemIndex = binarySearch(arr, elem, 0, arr.length);

      if(elemIndex == -1)
         System.out.println("-1,-1");

      int lowIndex = elemIndex - 1;
      int highIndex = elemIndex + 1;

      //Find the first index in the lower half of the array

      while(lowIndex >= 0 && (elemIndex = binarySearch(arr, elem, 0, lowIndex)) != -1)
         lowIndex = elemIndex -1;

      //Find the last index in the upper half of the array
      while(highIndex < arr.length && (elemIndex = binarySearch(arr, elem, highIndex, arr.length - 1)) != -1)
         highIndex = elemIndex + 1;

      System.out.println((lowIndex + 1) + ", " + (highIndex -1));

   }
```

I'm having difficulty trying to find the time complexity of the above program. Following is my approach:

From my understanding, the worst case will be when all the elements are same: `{3,3,3,3,3,3}`
Finding the first occurence will cost me: `O(logn) //Binary Search`

For each half of the array(upper and lower), I'm calling binarySearch at most `O(logn)` times. 
So, the total complexity will be `O(logn ^2)`

Is this the correct analysis? And, is `O(logn^2)` better than `O(n)`?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion, but I meant logn^2. Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

```
O(log2n) = O(log2+logn)
Now log2 is a constant. 
So O(log2n) = O(log2+logn) = O(1) + O(logn) = O(logn)
```

But your code does the binary search for any occurrence of a given integer. <- `log(n)`
Then it finds out its left most and right most occurrence. <- `log(a)+log(b)` where the first occurrence was at `a` and `a+b = n`.

So total complexity is `O(log(n)+log(a)+log(b)) = O(log(n*a*b)) = O(log(n))`

**Edit :** WAIT ! I misread your code. After finding the first occurrence you are finding, the left most and right most can be found in O(logn) time.

Basically, you can skip the first part of finding any occurrence and **can be done in O(logn)**. You have to give the conditions like this :

```
while A[i] != q or A[i-1] != A[i]:
    if A[i] < q: low = i + 1
    else: high: = i - 1
```

After ending the loop, `i` would be the left most occurrence of `q`.

```
while A[i] != q or A[i+1] != A[i]:
    if A[i] > q: high = i - 1
    else: low = i + 1
```

After ending the loop, `i` would be the right most occurrence of `q`.

Where `low` and `high` are the indexes from where to where you are finding your query and `i = low+high/2` at each step.

**WARNING :** You just have to handle some other cases, such that `i` never goes out of `[0..length of list-1]` or if there is no `q` in the list.

Both part takes `O(logn)` time, so total time-complexity would be `O(logn)` which is faster than `O((logn)^2)`

Comment: how do u initialize low and high to obtain i in the first iteration?

Comment: `low` = `0` and `high`= `len(list)`. so `i` = `low+high/2` = `len(list)/2`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the complexity:

If you meant `O((log(n))^2)`:

Define `m = log(n)`, and you get:

`O((log(n))^2) = O(m^2)`

`O(n) = O(e^log(n)) = O(e^m)`

Which shows `O((log(n))^2)` is asymptotically better than `O(n)`.

If you meant `O(log(2n)`:

`O(log(2n) = O(log(2)+log(n)) = O(log(n))`

So it is also better than `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the second part of the question. I also wanted to know, if O(log2n) is the correct complexity

Answer (score 0):

I have written program this way

```
int[] secondarr = new int[]{0,0,2,3,3,3,3,4,7,7,9};
    int searchNum = 3;
    int min = -1,max=-1;
    int noOfTimesLoopExecuted = 0;
    for(int ind=0, stop=0;ind<secondarr.length && stop==0;ind++) {
        if(searchNum>=secondarr[ind]){
            if(searchNum==secondarr[ind]){
            if(min==-1){
                min=ind;
            } else {
                max=ind;
            }
            }
        } else {
            stop = 1;
        }
        noOfTimesLoopExecuted = ind;
    }
    System.out.println("start index:"+min+","+"end index:"+max);
    System.out.println("noOfTimesLoopExecuted:"+noOfTimesLoopExecuted);
```